# Random links seo and spam

Tags: seo, spam

I built a mini-forum with social features for a client, to promote user registration, i planned to add a box on the forum pages to display pictures with profile links of random registered users.

I managed to make this random selection static for a day, i mean the list will be renewed each day and not change on every page refresh.

Could this random list of link could be harmful to seo by being considered as some kind of spam?

Comment: Are these "profile links" links within the profile that have been entered by the user? Or are you simply linking to the internal profile of a registered user?

Comment: All of these are internal links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There was a time when things like tag clouds have been considered suboptimal because of the potentially too-much links-problem, but what you do ("Members of the day"... "See some of our members"...) is just useful (See [this Mat Cutts Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnquaBa6DSk)).